# Criptografar senha em groovy

Tags: java, criptografia, script, groovy

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que terá uma tela de login que se baseará em dados (user, password) já salvos em um banco **MySQL**, e para isso pensei em aplicar o mesmo *Hash* que foi utilizado na primeira vez criptografar a senha do usuário para assim validar se o usuário que está tentando acessar a aplicação já está cadastrado no banco. É a primeira vez que faço algo relacionado a criptografia de senha,  então ao pesquisar referente ao assunto encontrei [esse](http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-funciona-a-criptografia-hash-em-java/31139) e [esse](http://blog.caelum.com.br/guardando-senhas-criptografadas-em-java/) conteúdo relacionado a criptografar a senha em **JAVA**, porém sempre que tento testar os códigos indicados nos *links* essa parte do código já acusa um erro no *script* em *Groovy*:

```
MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest("senha".getBytes("UTF-8")); \\O erro é na palavra byte mostra um erro
```

Erro exibido:

`Groovy:Primitive type literal: byte cannot be used as a method name at line: 22 column: 1. File:C:\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.3\workspace\default\src-providedGroovy\acript1494448116792.groovy @ line 22, column 1.`

Se tiverem uma dica de como posso criptografar uma variável do tipo string via script *Groovy*.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem duas opções

```
byte[] messageDigest = ...
```

Ou

```
def messageDigest = ...
```

Faz tempo da postagem, mas para referência futura.